Can we get page load time, responsive testing of the site and the time when the first pixel is painted onto the screen using karate framework
In the UI tests, can we add metrics like page load time, time to first paint i.e. The time when the first pixel is painted onto the screen, responsiveness, anything like that?
We are looking to see if we can keep track of how the site is scoring on top of the functional side of it using karate framework.

It may be possible to call chrome native functions to get performance data and "lighthouse" stats. Refer to this section of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test#devtools-protocol-tips
It is an area where you can potentially contribute as a blog post or to the project directly / open-source.
